# Is John Skilling's Nested Sampling Algorithm a Supervised or Unsupervised Learning Technique?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

Is John Skilling's Nested Sampling a Supervised or Unsupervised Learning Technique?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_sampling_algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested Sampling is not a learning algorithm, it is a technique for numerical integration.